# Importing/Exporting .csv list

Tags: python, csv

This is the script that actually exports the values in my five lists to a *.csv* file:

```
def exportEmployee(): # I moved the indentation over for clarity
import csv
with open('exportemployee.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    export_employee = csv.writer(csvfile)

    export_employee.writerows([employeeName_List, employeeSSN_List, employeePhone_List,employeeEmail_List, employeeSalary_List])
print("Employees' record exported to file.\n\n")
```

The funtionality works, but I am having an issue doing the reverse (importing):

```
def importEmployee(): # I moved the indentation over for clarity
    import csv

    f = open('importemployee.csv')

    data = []

    for line in f:
        data_line = line.rstrip().split(',')
        data.append(data_line)

    employeeName_List = data[0]
    employeeSSN_List = data[1]
    employeePhone_List = data[2]
    employeeEmail_List = data[3]
    employeeSalary_List = data[4]

# print(*employeeName_List, sep = ', ')
```

I print the lists outside of the import function, the lists are blank. However, if I print the list using `print(*employeeName_List, sep = ', ')` within the function it does return the values within the lists.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Is there any other way to import the csv file that has 5 rows of data back into the original 5 lists they stemmed from?

Answer (score 0):

Your `employeeXXX_List` variables are local variables, they only exist within the function's scope. if you want to use them outside, you have to return them - the simplest way being to just return `data` and eventually unpack it later if you want distinct lists:

```
def importEmployee():
    data = []
    # this makes sure your file will be closed
    with open('importemployee.csv') as f:
        for line in f:
            # using csv.reader would be safer...
            data_line = line.rstrip().split(',')
            data.append(data_line)

    return data

data = importEmployee()

employeeName_List = data[0]
employeeSSN_List = data[1]
employeePhone_List = data[2]
employeeEmail_List = data[3]
employeeSalary_List = data[4]
```

Note that structring your data this way (both at the csv level and in the Python code) is a **huge** design mistake since you rely on the items positions in the lists staying consistent, which is not garanteed (if your sort of the lists your data will be mixed up, one employee will get the email or SSN etc of another). The proper data structure is a list of `(name, ssn, phone, email, salary)` tuples, which also matches the expected csv structure where columns are the fields and lines the values (column 1 is the "name" field, column 2 is the "ssn" field etc).

Comment: Hello, I still need the values to remain within the function though, since this is just a small portion of a simple employee program. I need to be able to export data that was entered from those lists, or import the same information to those lists. Your solution works great, I just can't have it outside of that function. Is there an easier way to import/export using txt versus csv when working with five lists?

Comment: Hello, once I run my program it automatically pulls in the values from the list which I do not want... only when requested.

Comment: Then do it only when you need it. I thought it was obvious that the example code I posted was an example - how to integrate it in your real code is your job.